# Tomcat server not shutting down during first time

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat

I am developing a Queue message proof of concept on Spring-MVC 5.x, Java 8 and Tomcat server 9.x.  While reading the queue messages from the Oracle table, thread warning messages appending in the Catalina log file.

If I try to shutdown and start the tomcat server, the tomcat server is not shutting down during the first time but on the next call tomcat server is shutting down and a memory leak warning message is logged in the log file.

Please help why I am unable to shutdown the tomcat server during the first time.

Log details

```
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.Aprlifecyclelistener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path
INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.Abstract Protocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9090"]
INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]
INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 912 ms 
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.53]
INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/apps/opt/tomcat/webapps/Books.war]
WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.setVersion Unknown version string [4.0]. Default version will be used.
INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup: time and JSP compilation time.
INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/apps/opt/tomcat/webapps/Books.war] has finished in [62,365] ms
INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9090"] 
INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting Protocollandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 82019 ms
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.

INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9090"] 
INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferences Threads The web application [Books] appears to have started a thread named [AQThread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread: java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)

WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferences Threads The web application [Books] appears to have started a thread named [AQThread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a nemory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) 
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:282) 
oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:103)
oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:230)
oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:175)
oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:100)
oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:85) 
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamwWrapper.java:122)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamwrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:78)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1179)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarsha1SB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1155)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:279)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:202)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:1005)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecutewithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1307) 
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3449)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3493) 
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491) 
oracle.AQ.AQOracleQueue.dequeue(AQOracleQueue.java:1625) 
oracle.AQ.AQOracleQueue.dequeue(AQOracleQueue.java:1326)

INFO [AQThread] org.apache.catalina.loader WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [oracle.AQ.AQOracleQueue]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [oracle.AQ.AQOracleQueue]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1435)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1423)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1262) 
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1223)
```

Code sample

```
public void deQueMsg() throws AQException, SQLException {
java.sql.Connection dqConn = QueueConnection.getConnection(); // DB call
dqConn.setAutoCommit(false);
 
AQSession dqSess = null;
object 
}
 
//db connection
public Connection QueueConnection(String strJdbc)
{
    OracleDataSource OraDs;
    OraDs = new OracleDataSource();
    OraDs.setDriverType("thin");
    OraDs.setServerName("test");
    OraDs.setPortNumber(1521);
    OraDs.setDatabaseName("booksdb");
    OraDs.setUser("testusr");
    OraDs.setPassword("test123");
 
    return OraDs();
}
```

Comment: "Please help why I am unable to shutdown the tomcat server during the first time." Please help and [edit] your question to include some code that would allow us to tell you why the error occurred.

Comment: `AQThread` isn’t shut down when your application shuts down. It isn’t a daemon thread so Tomcat cannot shut down. You need to shut down `AQThread`.